# Ports Apache and ExpressJS

Tags: apache, node.js, ports

I am using Apache, which listens on port 80, expressjs and socket.io. Mainly, my question is in  which port should I make expressjs to listen to so that I do not need to write the port on the url.

Let's say I want to get the id of this url:

```
localhost/web/:id
```

The problem is that if I have Apache running on port 80, then expressjs won't recognize that url, so I should write it like this [if I have app.listen(81)]:

```
localhost:81/web/:id
```

Which is actually unreal because I can't make the user to write :81
I've read something about http-node-proxy, but don't understand pretty well

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to run both Apache and Node?

If its a requirement, you're going to need to come up with a way to forward a particular route/path on to the particular server you're hosting resources on. This is called a reverse http proxy.

You can:

- Run Apache on port 80 and forward a subset of urls onto node, which will run on a non-80 port - http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies
- Run node on port 80 and use something like node-http-proxy to set up route forwarding - http://blog.nodejitsu.com/http-proxy-intro
- Run something like ngnix as the reverse proxy, and have both apache and node on non-80 ports - http://www.ubuntugeek.com/using-nginx-as-a-reverse-proxy-to-get-the-most-out-of-your-vps.html

Or... collapse your servers and just use node. Node can do static file hosting (not super well, but that's all relative)